# Static Dropdown in Jqgrid edit popup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid for basic CRUD functionality on an asp.net mvc page. My requirement is that I want to show a dropdown on edit popup that will only contain static values e.g New and Existing. All the examples I find use `editoptions` with `dataurl` and `buildselect` method. Is there a way that I can build select list using static values when grid opens?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple. You need just use `value` property of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions). Something like

```
{ name: "myColName", width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "select",
    editoptions: { value: "New:New;Existing:Existing", defaultValue: "New" }}
```

or if you use toolbar searching additionally then

```
{ name: "myColName", width: 100, editable: true, edittype: "select", stype: 'select',
    editoptions: { value: "New:New;Existing:Existing", defaultValue: "New" },
    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;New:New;Existing:Existing' }}
```

Comment: thanks Oleg, it worked. One more question, how can I change the label in front of any control (dropdown or textbox). By default it simply prints the name of the column.

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelZahid: You are welcome! I suppose that you use form editing mode. In the case you can use `label` property of [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions). Per defaults jqGrid use the value from `colName`. To overwrite the rule you can add `formoptions: {label: "My new label"}`